# PlotStyle and Legends

Tags: plotting

I know only three plot style

```
m = 1;
w = 1;
U = m*w^2 z^2/2;
p1 = Plot[U, {z, -1, 1}, PlotStyle -> Dashed]
p2 = Plot[U/2, {z, -1, 1}, PlotStyle -> Dotted]
p3 = Plot[U/3, {z, -1, 1}, PlotStyle -> DotDashed]
Show[p1, p2, p3] ![Superimposed, p1, p2, p3][2]
```

as shown. How to get more options for line style as I need to show more plots and I also need to show the legends to specify which plot is corresponding to what.

[image: superimposed p1, p2 , p3]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can read the documentation of [`PlotStyle`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotStyle.html) under *Details*.

Using [`Thickness`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Thickness.html), [`Dashing`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dashing.html) and [`RGBColor`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RGBColor.html) or  [`Hue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Hue.html) may help.

Here for 80 distinctive styles.

```
Block[
 {
  styles = Flatten[
    Table[
     {Hue[h], Thickness[t], Dashing[{d1, d2, d3}]}
     , {h, 0, 0.9, 0.2}
     , {t, {0.001, 0.003}}
     , {d1, {0.01, 0.02}}
     , {d2, {0.005, 0.02}}
     , {d3, {0.02, 0.03}}], 4]
  },
 Plot[
  Evaluate@Table[y, {y, -1, 1, 2/(Length[styles] - 1)}]
  , {x, -1, 1}
  , PlotRange -> {-1, 1}
  , PlotStyle -> styles
  ]]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

If you want to encode information in the dashing using Morse code, see [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/66267/10397)

Comment: Yes, but does the Morse code say anything nice?

Comment: @rcollyer challenge accepted, please see [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/66267/10397)

Comment: @rhermans Thank you very much for providing an extensive list of dashing styles and options.