# How to write Morse code into Plot Dashing?

Tags: plotting, style

How can we define a dashing pattern in a plot such that it reads arbitrary text in Morse code?

For instance

```
Graphics[{DotDashed, Line[{{0, 0}, {5, 0}}]}]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

this could be interpreted as "**.-**" that is "*a*" in Morse code.

Proper spacing would be desirable in order to distinguish "**.-**" (*a*) from "**-.**" (*n*).

(*Inspired by @rcollyer's comment to my answer to [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/66251/plotstyle-and-legends/66253)*.)

Comment: I can't properly express how amused I am that my flippant remark has resulted in this. +1 to both.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

First define the Morse code (from [rosettacode.org](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Morse_code) with corrections by @evanb)

```
morsecode = (#1 -> Characters[#2]) & @@@ {
   {"a", ".-"}, {"b", "-..."}, {"c", "-.-."},
   {"d", "-.."}, {"e", "."}, {"f", "..-."},
   {"g", "--."}, {"h", "...."}, {"i", ".."},
   {"j", ".---"}, {"k", "-.-"}, {"l", ".-.."},
   {"m", "--"}, {"n", "-."}, {"o", "---"},
   {"p", ".--."}, {"q", "--.-"}, {"r", ".-."},
   {"s", "..."}, {"t", "-"}, {"u", "..-"},
   {"v", "...-"}, {"w", ".--"}, {"x", "-..-"},
   {"y", "-.--"}, {"z", "--.."}, {"0", "-----"},
   {"1", ".----"}, {"2", "..---"}, {"3", "...--"},
   {"4", "....-"}, {"5", "....."}, {"6", "-...."},
   {"7", "--..."}, {"8", "---.."}, {"9", "----."}
   };
```

Use [`AbsoluteDashing`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AbsoluteDashing.html) and define dots as short dashed, lines as long dashes and include proper spacing between symbols and characters.

```
morserule =  Append[(#[[1]] -> Append[Riffle[#[[2]], 3], 12]) & /@ (morsecode /. {"." -> 2 , "-" -> 7}), " " -> {0, 17}];

toMorseDash[s_String] :=  Flatten[Characters[ToLowerCase@s] /. morserule]
```

Now we can test in a simple line.

```
Graphics[{Thickness[0.02], AbsoluteDashing[toMorseDash[" Morse Code "]], Line[{{0, 0}, {15, 0}}]}]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

For plots, use `PlotStyle-> AbsoluteDashing[toMorseDash["text"]]`

```
Plot[Sin[t], {t, 0, 4 Pi}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, AbsoluteDashing[toMorseDash[" Sine Wave"]]}]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: NB: the original post had the same encodings for 1-4 as 6-9. This is now fixed.

Comment: Or `WolframAlpha["Morse code \"Dot/Dash Pattern\"",{{"MorseCodeTranslation", 1}, "Plaintext"}]` :)

Comment: The only thing missing at this point is the corresponding sound with the "di"'s and "da"'s... :D