# What is better color scheme to show more constrast in this case?

Tags: plotting, functions, color, legending, visualization

Is there a better color scheme to make the lines and legends boxes more contranst?

 I'm using `ColorData[97]` but there are some colors that look similar so I'm looking for a better color scheme. 
As you can see from the image below pairs `6, 16`, `1,7`, `9,14` look similar.

[image]

```
*colors = ColorData[97] /@ Range[24];
list = {{"a"}, {"b", "c"}, {"d"}, {"e"}, {"f"}, {"g"}, {"h", 
    "k"}, {"l"}, {"m"}, {"n"}, {"p", "q", 
    "k"}, {"x"}, {"y"}, {"z"}, {"kh"}, {"xy"}, {"cy"}, {"cz"}};
linelegend = 
  LineLegend[{Opacity[opacity, Gray], 
    Directive[Red, Thickness[0.01], Dashed], White}, 
   Style[#, 30, Bold, Black] & /@ {"mnk", "htk", "kn"}, 
   "LegendItem" -> {"Square", Automatic, "Square"}, 
   LegendMarkerSize -> 25];
opacity = 0.2;
Dynamic[Legended[
  Row[{Plot[{x^2 - 1, 2 x - 3, 5 - 3 x, 5 x - 2 x^2, x^2/3, x^2/3 - 2,
       x^2/3 - 6, 2 x^2 - 1, 2 /3 x - 3, 1 - 3 x, 5/4 x - 2 , x^2 - 9,
       5 x^2/3, 8 x^2/3 - 2, 9 x^2/3 - 6, 1/(2 x), 1/(x - 1), x^2/(
      x - 3), 5 - 1/(3 x + 1), x^3/(6 x^2 + 3), x^5/(6 x - 3), 1/(
      x^2 + 9), 1/(8 - x), 1/(1 - 5 x)}, {x, 0, 6}, 
     GridLines -> Automatic, 
     PlotStyle -> 
      ReplacePart[
       Directive[#, Thickness[0.005]] & /@ 
        colors, {Except[Alternatives @@ n]} -> 
        Directive[Opacity[.01], Gray]], Ticks -> Automatic, 
     Frame -> True, Axes -> True, PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.5], 
     PlotRange -> {{0, 6}, {0, 6}}, 
     FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, 20], GridLines -> Automatic,
      GridLinesStyle -> LightGray, Ticks -> Automatic, 
     TicksStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, 20], ImageSize -> 800], 
    Spacer[10], linelegend}], 
  Placed[{Spacer@{0, 20}, 
     TogglerBar[Dynamic[n], 
      MapIndexed[#2[[1]] -> 
         ToString[
           Framed[Style[#2[[1]], Black, Bold, 15], 
            ImageSize -> {45, 45}, Alignment -> Center, 
            Background -> colors[[#2[[1]]]]], StandardForm] <> 
          ToString[
           Framed[Style[#, Black, Bold, 15], ImageSize -> {230, 45}, 
            Alignment -> Center, Background -> White], 
           StandardForm] &, list], 
      Appearance -> "Vertical" -> {Automatic, 3}]} // Column, {Left, 
    Below}]]]*
```

Comment: Do any of the 100+ other indexed color schemes work for you? E.g., wrap a Manipulate around your code with a control to pick the color index a value other than 97.

Comment: @tad nice idea. I tried from 1 to 114. It seems that 54, 60, 97 are the best but there is always pairs with similar color.

Comment: If you really must have all of those curves on a single figure, you might consider having at least two different thicknesses and/or line types (solid and dotted).

Comment: @JimB that is also one way to do it but I prefer colors if it's possible.

Comment: If intended to present to others, remember some will have different color perception than you. So JimB's suggestion for different line types will be more robust.

Comment: You can always label the curves with [Morse Code](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/66268/10397)

Comment: Something like `styles=Compose[AbsoluteDashing,toMorseDash,ToString[#]]&/@Range[Length[fncs]]`, where `fncs` is the list of functions to plot and `toMorseDashing` is from the question linked in the previous comment.

Comment: Most of the categorical color schemes have 10 colors (``Histogram[ColorData[#, "Range"][[2]] & /@ Range[93]]``), and this is with a good reason. If you *really* insist on having 18 different colors, you can use a bright color scheme (such as 3), and then adding manually some common missing colors: ``colors = (ColorData[3] /@ Range[10])~Join~{Brown, Gray, LightGray, Cyan, Magenta, RGBColor[0.545876, 1, 0.558755], RGBColor[1, 0.753262, 0.0437629], RGBColor[0.443442, 0.110262, 0.100633]};``

Comment: You could use something like `colors=Table[Hue[i, 0.5, 1.0], {i, 1/18, 1, 1/18}]`. Which provide will evenly spaced hues. Playing around with the second argument for saturation, 0.5 seems to give the most easily distinguishable colors. But you still end up with some pink/purples that look close to me. You could also choose only 9 hues and add two steps in value, or saturation to make it a little easier to tell the difference. I also agree that color isn't the way to go here though.

Comment: Number of curves: https://thebrain.mcgill.ca/flash/capsules/experience_jaune03.html would suggest 7 items +/-2 is a limit for items that can be retained in short term memory. Number of colors that humans can distinguish: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_vision : 10million according to this site. Board rooms are different. There you use the theme "Marketing" with one or two thick lines. If you say what you are trying to visualize, then I am sure someone will suggest an alternate visualization.

Answer (score 4):

6 colors evenly spaced in Hue:
`n=18;`
`a = Table[Hue[h, 1, 1], {h, 0, 1 - 3/n, 3/n}]`
[image]

6 colors, offset in hue from above, with .75 brightness:
`b = Table[Hue[h, 1, .75], {h, 1/n, 1 - 2/n, 3/n}]`
[image]

6 colors, offset in hue from above, with 0.3 saturation:
`c = Table[Hue[h, .3, 1], {h, 2/n, 1 - 1/n, 3/n}]`
[image]

Put them all together:
`mycolors2 = SortBy[Join[a, b, c], Hue]`
[image]

Plot:
[image]